# SBT: 'sources' task returns nothing

Tags: sbt

Why command "sources" returns nothing when called from the sbt console?

```
[info] Loading project definition from E:\Git\sbt-coveralls\project
[info] Set current project to sbt-coveralls (in build file:/E:/Git/sbt-coveralls/)
> sources
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 13, 2015 10:17:33 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the return value of a setting you need to use `show`:

```
> show sources
[info] ArrayBuffer(/Users/dnw/Desktop/t-2015-07-13.1202/Hi.scala)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 13-Jul-2015 12:02:52
```